# Compiler Error C2955

Tags: c++

I m studying pointers and templates, and trying to create double linked list with templates. Compiler throws C2955 in 15 line.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct s_node
{
    T value;
    s_node *p_next;
    s_node *p_prev;
};

template<typename T>
s_node* createNode(s_node *p_parent = NULL) {

    s_node *p_newNode = new s_node;

    p_newNode->value = 0;
    p_newNode->p_next = NULL;

    if (p_parent != NULL) {
        p_parent->p_next = p_newNode;
    }

    return p_newNode;
}
```

Comment: C2955 doesn't mean anything to us without looking it up. Please paste the full error in the question.

Comment: I wonder what line 15 may be. Don't make use guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory:

```
error C2955: 's_node': use of class template requires template argument list
```

`s_node` is a class template.

Change the code like this:

```
template<typename T>
s_node<T>* createNode(s_node<T> *p_parent = NULL) {

  s_node<T> *p_newNode = new s_node<T>();

  p_newNode->value = 0;
  p_newNode->p_next = NULL;

  if (p_parent != NULL) {
    p_parent->p_next = p_newNode;
  }

  return p_newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> error C2955: 's_node': use of class template requires template
>   argument list

The above error is very obvious to what the issue is.

The usage `s_node *p_newNode = new s_node;` is wrong. You should be doing this instead:

```
s_node<T> *p_newNode = new s_node<T>;
```

You require the template arguments for a templated class. In addition, the class return type needs to be:

```
s_node<T>* createNode(s_node *p_parent = NULL) {
//....
}
```

**Side Note**: As a recommendation, use `nullptr`, instead of `NULL`, it is more modern.